Fetching Project Item Status with GitHub GraphQL API
I'm trying to retrieve the "Status" of issues within a GitHub Project using the GraphQL API. I'm using the fieldValueByName directive to access the custom field, but I'm encountering an error: KeyError("The 'data' field is missing from the response. Check your query or token permissions.")
GraphQL
fieldValueByName(name: "Status") {
  ... on ProjectV2ItemFieldSingleSelectValue { 
    status 
  }
}

This query results in the following error:
JSON
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "query",
        "organization",
        "projectV2",
        "items",
        "nodes",
        "fieldValueByName",
        "... on ProjectV2ItemFieldSingleSelectValue",
        "status"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "undefinedField",
        "typeName": "ProjectV2ItemFieldSingleSelectValue",
        "fieldName": "status"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 40,
          "column": 19
        }
      ],
      "message": "Field 'status' doesn't exist on type 'ProjectV2ItemFieldSingleSelectValue'"
    }
  ]
}

I've also tried variations like:
GraphQL
... on ProjectV2ItemFieldCustomSingleSelectValue { 
  customFieldSingleSelectValue { 
    value 
  } 
}

But I'm still unable to retrieve the "Status" value correctly.
What am I doing wrong?
How can I correctly query the "Status" field of a project item using the GitHub GraphQL API?
Is there a specific field name or type I should be using instead of status or customFieldSingleSelectValue?
Relevant Code Snippet:
GraphQL
query($cursor: String) {
  organization(login: "your-organization") {
    projectV2(number: 123) { 
      items(first: 100, after: $cursor) {
        nodes {
          id
          content {
            ... on Issue { 
              # ... issue fields 
            }
          }
          fieldValueByName(name: "Status") { 
            # ... field value query 
          }
        }
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
          endCursor
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

I appreciate any help or guidance you can provide!
I'm trying to retrieve the "Status" of issues within a GitHub Project using the GraphQL API. I'm using the fieldValueByName directive to access the custom field, but I'm encountering an error: KeyError("The 'data' field is missing from the response. Check your query or token permissions.")
